# Firestore rules allow access to docs, but not via collection query

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Moving from firebase to firestore, and hoping this is just something I haven't understood about firestore rules. I have a collection of docs, and a user record which stores which docs that user is allowed to read. My docs look something like this:

```
/eventDetails/abc123
  name: "Event name"
  description: "Event description"
  id: "abc123"
```

and my rules look like this:

```
    match /eventDetails/{eventId} {
        allow read: if isEventMember(eventId);
    }

    function isEventMember(eventId) {
      return eventId in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.events.keys();
    }
```

In code, I can access individual docs in `/eventDetails` by id, but accessing them via a collection query fails with insufficient permissions:

```
  for (const eventId of eventIds) {
    await fsFirestore().collection('eventDetails').doc(eventId).get()
      .then(snap => { console.log('got doc snap:', snap)})
      .catch(err => { console.log('caught error'); console.error(err) })
  }
  await fsFirestore().collection('eventDetails').where('id', 'in', eventIds).get()
    .then(snap => { console.log('got collection snap:', snap)})
    .catch(err => { console.log('caught error'); console.error(err) })
```

The `for()` loop all works fine (assuming I pass in a list of `eventIds` that the user *should* be able to access), and I also see an error there if I pass in an `eventId` that they *shouldn't* be able to access. All correct so far, and so I'm pretty sure the `isEventMember()` function in the rules is doing what it should.

But accessing the very same docs via the collection query (all docs have an `id` property with matching value) fails with `Missing or insufficient permissions.` This seems counter to the example on [this page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#rules_are_not_filters).

Is it possible to get a collection of documents using a query in this way, whilst still preventing a user from access other documents?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that [Firebase security rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#rules_are_not_filters).  Please read that documentation.  Rules will not take the results of a query and remove items that would not satisfy the rule.  Queries are all-or-nothing.  If anything in the results set *might* not pass a rule, the entire query is rejected.

What you should do instead is simply `get()` each event ID separately by iterating `eventIds`, instead of using an "in" query.  This allows security rules to know exactly which pair of event ID and UID to check for each query so it can pass or fail each query individually.  I know it seems like a hassle, but this is required because of the way rules work.

Comment: I'm not trying to use the rules as a filter. I'm using the `where()` function as the filter. Queries _can_ be used like this according to that documentation page I linked to. The array passed in via `where()` is static (not a function), and so nothing should prevent the sdk from checking against each key...

Comment: Effectively, you are.  It's not the where clause per se, it's the fact that your rules need to do an auxiliary lookup on each matching document in order to determine if it should be returned.  That simply does not scale, and Firestore will not allow it - imagine what that would mean for very large collections.  I know it's a hassle, but you will have to split up your queries.  If you would like to see different behavior, file a feature request with Firebase support.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: So, the rules will work for `.doc()` but not for `.collection().where()`? That's really not very intuitive, and I certainly didn't get that distinction from the documentation. I also don't quite see the difference between me making 6 `.doc()` requests vs a `.where()` with 6 things in an array. They will all count as read requests and be billed, no?

Comment: BTW, I'm trying to bind the result of this collection for real time updates, not just get the data once. That becomes really difficult to manage if each doc needs to be bound separately.

Comment: Yes, as I said, it's kind of a hassle.  You don't really have a workaround.  The number or reads does not change in either case.

Comment: Doug, I'm not sure if this is my misunderstanding of your explanation, or your misunderstanding of what I was trying to do. But having read the documentation page again, I was convinced what I was after was possible. I've submitted an answer—be grateful if you could comment on whether it's correct, or working 'by accident', as it still uses the auxiliary lookup you said was the problem, and yet it seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

Reading [this section](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#secure_and_query_documents_based_on_authuid) of the documentation, I was convinced what I was trying to do was possible. And then this sentence gave me a clue:

> In contrast, the following query succeeds, because it includes the same constraint on the author field as the security rules:

Since my query restricts the collection result to documents in `eventDetails` where the `id` field of the document is in the set of events the user is allowed to access, I changed my security rules function to:

```
function isEventMember() {
  return resource.data.id in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.events.keys();
}
```

By accessing the event id as `resource.data.id` instead of the path matching wildcard `{eventId}`, the rules appear to work exactly as I would expect. It's still not ideal because if, for some reason, the `id` field in an event is changed, corrupted, or otherwise set incorrectly, it could allow access to a document the user shouldn't have access to. For example, if the user's `events` field was set so they were only allowed to access doc `abc123`, but the data was set like this:

```
/eventDetails/abc123
{
  name: "Accessible event",
  id: "abc123"
},

/eventDetails/secret234
{
  name: "Private event",
  id: "abc123"
}
```

Then the user *would* be able to access `/eventDetails/secret234`. But since the only place in my code where the `id` field is set is in a firebase function triggered on event creation, I can be pretty confident this wouldn't happen.

Comment: Note there is one minor annoyance with this approach, which is that if a user is 'removed' from an event (e.g. the event key is removed from their `events` object), the firestore 'Missing or insufficient permissions.' error is raised _before_ my app sees the change to the user object. So I can't pre-emptively update the collection query binding. But it's just minor annoyance and doesn't affect the app itself.

Comment: Thank you SO much for pointing out that resource.data.id is the right way, instead of using a wildcard `{eventId}`.